# Django ModelForm's DateTime value being localized/translated with localization turned off

Tags: python, html, django, datetime

So I'm working on this Activity management platform, we are using Django 3.0.4. Before I expose my problem, I must say that I'm somewhat new to Django and python itself.

My current objetive is to allow the administrator to set specific dates for specific events. Initially the page must show the current dates and details. That I can already the do with the code shown below

This is an example of the model used to store the dates

```
class Dates(models.Model):

    id = models.AutoField(db_column='ID', primary_key=True)
    datestart = models.DateTimeField(db_column='DateStart')
    dateend = models.DateTimeField(db_column='DateEnd')

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Dates'
```

This is my form

```
class dateForm(forms.ModelForm):  
    class Meta:  
        model = Dates
        exclude = ['id']
```

And this is my current view function

```
def editdates(request):
    dates_current = Dates.objects.get(id=1)
    dates_form = dateForm(instance=dates_current)

    if request.method == 'POST':

        submitted_data = request.POST.copy() #Might need to change incoming data before saving to db
        dates_form = diaAbertoSettingsForm(submitted_data, instance=dates_current) #Generate form with existing data

        if dates_form.is_valid():
            dates_form.save()

    return render(request=request,
                template_name = 'dates/edit.html',
                context = {'form': dates_form})
```

The same page that shows the data (dates) must also allow you to submit a change, this would be relatively easy to do. The real problem starts when I want to submit the form.

Currently, I do the following to display the current values

```
<div class="column">
  <div class="field">
    {% if form.datestart.errors %}
      <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <strong>{{form.datestart.errors}}</strong>
      </div>
    {% endif %}
    <label class="label">Date Start</label>
    <div class="control">
      <input class="input" type="text" name="datestart" value='{{form.datestart.value}}'>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Which is all fine, until you see that the result from `{{form.datestart.value}}` is **not** a normal "YY-MM-DD H:M:S" dateTime (e.g. 2000-01-01 00:00:00) format like you'd expect, but a "Written out" format like "Jan. 1, 2000, midnight" which obviously causes problems when I want the user to edit this date. If they were to keep the format, the form would return an error saying the format of the dateTime is invalid.

To fix this problem I've tried the following:

1. Turning off "[Format Localization](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/formatting/)" in settings.py and on a template by template basis
2. Turning off "[Translation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/translation/)", same as above
3. I've tried using the date filters described in the [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#date)
4. I've also tried using the [datetime parser from django utils](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/utils/#django.utils.dateparse.parse_datetime)

I've also looked around on other sources besides the documentation but none seem to share my problem.

If I were to place `{{form.datestart}}` instead of `{{form.datestart.value}}`, would indeed make it come out correct, but since I want to use a classes from bulma, I don't see a way around it.

How can I make it so the `{{form.datestart.value}}` comes out as `2000-01-01 00:00:00` and not as `Jan. 1, 2000, midnight` ?

This is only an example, the real model has about 10 diferent start/end dates, so a way to keep automated it, would be ideal but not required.

Comment: If [date](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#date) filter is not working, could it be that `form.datestart.value` is a string? What if you [override](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/formatting/#locale-aware-input-in-forms) it in the form?

Comment: I tried that just now, but the output stays the same. `Jan. 1, 2000, midnight`
What bothers me most is when I print the form `print(dates_form)` there's a line like this: `<input type="text" name="datestart" value="2000-01-01 00:00:00" required id="id_datestart">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. The solution was rather easy and in hindsight It's what I should've done in the beginning.

First of all, I turned off localization globally. Secondly I changed my modelForm to the following

```
class dateForm(forms.ModelForm):  
    class Meta:  
        model = Dates
        exclude = ['id']
        widgets = {
            'datestart': DateTimeInput(attrs={'class': 'input'})
        }
```

This allowed me to give custom classes to my fields. Then in the template I replaced `<input class="input" type="text" name="datestart" value='{{form.datestart.value}}'>` with the complete field `{{form.datestart}}`.